# PostgreSQL How to add WHERE where is count() and GROUP

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I add WHERE function into my query ?

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('year', "createdAt") AS txn_year 
FROM tables
WHERE active = 1  // not working I don't know why 
GROUP BY txn_year;
```

Thanks for any opinion

Comment: The real problem here is that you are not reading the error message and trying to understand what sort of problem might cause it. It is laid out for you right there: "operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 3: WHERE active = 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`active` is of type `character varying`, i.e. a string type. This should work:

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('year', "createdAt") AS txn_year 
FROM tables
WHERE active = '1'
GROUP BY txn_year;
```

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL supports booleans, so you might consider changing active to be a true/false boolean.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('year', "createdAt") AS txn_year 
FROM tables 
WHERE column_active = 1
GROUP BY txn_year;
```

Comment: EROOR: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: that is because I don't know what "column_active" is. Substitute that with whatever the column name is and make sure that the datatype is an integer 1 or a varchar '1' i.e. WHERE columnnamegoeshere = 1  or WHERE columnnamegoeshere = '1'

Comment: it is column called "active" like you can see now.... I don't understand why is not workiing, I tried already this before...

Comment: Wow i gave you the answer. Gave some other schmuck points tsk tsk